# FreeBSD SSH terminal windows

Tags: ssh, terminal, freebsd, ncurses

When I run a ncurses-based tool, say `nano`, in a Linux/OSX SSH session and then close it, the terminal session is back with the history and everything.

But if I start `nano` in a FreeBSD SSH session and then close it, nano's window doesn't clear up and the terminal history doesn't show up again.
I recall the same experience a long time ago, when working on a text console Linux, but never cared about it.

So, my question is: How can I make FreeBSD's SSH behave like Linux/OSX'es SSH?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Here are 2 screenshots of what I get on OSX and FreeBSD: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B57e.jpg

Comment: This might be of interested (a post on tput and alternative screens).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @Hennes, thanks. Finally figured it out - FreeBSD's termcap database is quite old and I had to override the `xterm-256color` settings. I've answered my own question in case someone stumbles upon the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, to answer my own question...

After reading this question: [OpenSSH, FreeBSD screen overwrite when closing application](https://superuser.com/questions/715125/openssh-freebsd-screen-overwrite-when-closing-application?rq=1)
I decided to get familiar with `termcap` and after a few headbangs I finally made it work as expected.

Below I provide the entries to my $HOME/.termcap

```
# $HOME/.termcap
xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors and clear:\
    :Co#256:pa#32767:\
    :AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm:\
    :tc=xterm-new:tc=xterm-clear:
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can fix this for all users by editing the following definition in in `/etc/termcap`:

```
xterm-256color|xterm alias 3:\
    :Co#256:pa#32767:\
    :AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm:tc=xterm-new:
```

Replace `:tc=xterm-new:` with `:tc=xterm-clear:` so that it says:

```
xterm-256color|xterm alias 3:\
    :Co#256:pa#32767:\
    :AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm:tc=xterm-clear:
```

Then run:

```
cap_mkdb -f /usr/share/misc/termcap /etc/termcap
```